# accessing mdi controls dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I am facing a strange issue. 
I have a mdi Form which contains a menustrip. I have no problem to access the menustrip when coding inside the class (MyMDI.cs) itself by writing:

```
this.menuStrip
```

But if I am trying to access the menuStrip from another class, it will not work.

```
MyMDI mdi = new MyMDI();
mdi.menuStrip
```

I am getting the error:
Error   2   'MyMDI' does not contain a definition for 'MenuStrip'

Comment: Is menuStrip public?

Comment: No, just realized it was not (already answered). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just realized it is a private field.
menuStrip property is private by default.
In order to access it, I added a readonly property to MyMDI class:

```
    public MenuStrip MenuStrip
    {
        get { return this.menuStrip; }
    }
```